# heroku rake aborted! could not connect to server: Connection timed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

Recently I have resetted my database on heroku by the below command.

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
```

And I have ran the below command.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

The response I have received is shown below.

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "ec2-23-23-203-225.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There has been shared db issues today I can see on status.heroku.com - does it still do it now? Chances are you were affected by an outage of a shared DB server.